# Best Practice for Nuxt.js and Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, database, vue.js, nuxt.js

I got some project to make a blogging-like SSR app with firebase. I found this boilerplate https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-firebase-auth, and it's worked well but it just use cloud functions. Is there any of best practice to fetch data from realtime database before rendering the page using that boilerplate or maybe any other way? I got stuck with that.

Comment: You should include the relevant code, not just point to it.

Comment: Maybe this video help a lot for you https://youtu.be/ZYUWsjUxxUQ

Answer (score -1):

I had tried and i found there are two options i dont have any solution for Firebase/Firestore on NUXT SSR mode

for SSR mode... work for firestore and realtime database but it's not realtime processing

you can fetch data on asyncData method in component or nutServerInit method on actions Vuex

if you want realtime working like firestore you have to use SPA mode on nuxt but it's not good for SEO

you can fetch data on asyncData method in component or nuxtClientInit method on actions Vuex

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYUWsjUxxUQ&feature=youtu.be

above video not working for realtime processing but it work for SSR 
it was using ismorphicfetch for realtime database but not for Forestore

deploying NUXT SSR on Cloud Function it need a little tweak Cloud Function still beta not yet support node v8